# Java - Logic error appending a user input to an ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that allows the users to create a custom playlist. I have currently gotten all inputs, assigned them values and placed them in an object.

However, when I try to append this object to an ArrayObject, it only appends `int duration`, and upon output, it simply prints

> Duration: X
> *(with X being the value inputted by the user).*

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Track {
    public String title, artist, genre;
    public int duration;
    
    public Track(String title, String artist, String genre, int duration) {
        this.title = title; //ti
        this.artist = artist; //t
        this.genre = genre; //d
        this.duration = duration; //id
    }
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }   

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }
    
    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }
    
    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }
    
    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
    
    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
    
    public void printEntry() { 
        System.out.print("Title: "+title+"\nArtist: "+artist+"\nType: "+genre+"\n"+toString());
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Duration: "+duration;
    }
}
```

```
class MyPlaylist {
    private ArrayList<Track> songList;
    private static int songCount = 0;
    public static boolean programActive = true;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        while (programActive) {
            userInterface();
        }
    }
    
    public MyPlaylist() {
        songList = new ArrayList<Track>();
    }
    
    public MyPlaylist(Track entry) {
        songList = new ArrayList<Track>();
        songList.add(entry);
    }
    
    public void addEntry (Track entry) {
        songList.add(entry);
    }   

    public void printList(Track[] songs) {
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++){
            songs[i].printEntry();
        }
    }

    public Track[] getPlaylist() {
        Track[] l = new Track[songList.size()];
        System.out.println(songList.size());
        
        for(int i = 0; i < l.length; i++){
            l[i] = songList.get(i);
        }
        
        return l;
    }
    
    public void deleteTrack(int trackNum) {
        
    }
    

    // --- MAIN USER INTERFACE ---
    private static void userInterface() {
        MyPlaylist songPlaylist = new MyPlaylist();
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
            System.out.println("\n1 - Add a new song\n2 - List all songs\n3 - Delete an existing song\n4 - Search for a song\n5 - Display total playtime\n6 - exit\nPlease enter your choice:");
            int input = userInput.nextInt();
        
            switch (input) {
            case 1: 
                Scanner newSongEntry = new Scanner(System.in); 

                System.out.println("\nTitle of the song:");
                String title = newSongEntry.nextLine(); 
                
                
                System.out.println("Name of the artist:");
                String artist = newSongEntry.nextLine(); 


                System.out.println("Type of the song:");
                String genre = newSongEntry.nextLine(); 


                System.out.println("Duration (seconds):");
                int duration = newSongEntry.nextInt(); 

                Track newEntry = new Track(title, artist, genre, duration);
                songPlaylist.addEntry(newEntry);

                break;
        
            case 2:
                songPlaylist.printList(songPlaylist.getPlaylist());
                break;
        
            case 3:
                break;
        
            case 4:
                break;
        
            case 5:
                break;

            case 6:
                System.out.println("\nThank you. Bye!");
                programActive = false;
        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're declaring `songPlaylist` in `userInterface()`, the playlist is being remade from scratch after every time you perform and action on it.

I would suggest declaring `songPlaylist` in main() and passing it to `userInterface` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        MyPlaylist songPlaylist = new MyPlaylist();
        while (programActive) {
            userInterface(songPlaylist);
        }
    }
```

and this paramater for `userInterface`:

```
private static void userInterface(MyPlaylist songPlaylist) { ... }
```

so you can keep the code inside `userInterface`

Answer (score 0):

Declare `songPlaylist` as a class level variable.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyPlaylist {
    private ArrayList<Track> songList;
    private static int songCount = 0;
    public static boolean programActive = true;
    public static MyPlaylist songPlaylist = new MyPlaylist();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (programActive) {
            userInterface();
        }
    }

    public MyPlaylist() {
        songList = new ArrayList<Track>();
    }

    public MyPlaylist(Track entry) {
        songList = new ArrayList<Track>();
        songList.add(entry);
    }

    public void addEntry(Track entry) {
        songList.add(entry);
    }

    public void printList(Track[] songs) {
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
            songs[i].printEntry();
        }
    }

    public Track[] getPlaylist() {
        Track[] l = new Track[songList.size()];
        System.out.println(songList.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
            l[i] = songList.get(i);
        }

        return l;
    }

    public void deleteTrack(int trackNum) {

    }


    // --- MAIN USER INTERFACE ---
    private static void userInterface() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\n1 - Add a new song\n2 - List all songs\n3 - Delete an existing song\n4 - Search for a song\n5 - Display total playtime\n6 - exit\nPlease enter your choice:");
        int input = userInput.nextInt();

        switch (input) {
            case 1:
                Scanner newSongEntry = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("\nTitle of the song:");
                String title = newSongEntry.nextLine();


                System.out.println("Name of the artist:");
                String artist = newSongEntry.nextLine();


                System.out.println("Type of the song:");
                String genre = newSongEntry.nextLine();


                System.out.println("Duration (seconds):");
                int duration = newSongEntry.nextInt();

                Track newEntry = new Track(title, artist, genre, duration);
                songPlaylist.addEntry(newEntry);

                break;

            case 2:
                songPlaylist.printList(songPlaylist.getPlaylist());
                break;

            case 3:
                break;

            case 4:
                break;

            case 5:
                break;

            case 6:
                System.out.println("\nThank you. Bye!");
                programActive = false;

        }
    }
}
```